# Papervision Render to Movie or Film Strip

Tags: caching, rendering, movie, papervision3d

I am looking BitmapViewport3D for rendering to a texture, and I am wondering if there is a way to render to a movie or film strip for later viewing. Anything like that built into PaperVision?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.papervision3d.materials.MovieAssetMaterial;
var material:MovieAssetMaterial = new MovieAssetMaterial("material",false,true);
plane = new Plane(material,500,500); scene.addChild(plane);
```

"material" is the linkage ID from the asset in the library that you want to apply as the material.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this answers my question. This seems to be how to use a movie as a texture. That is not the part I am confused about. I want to know how to render the whole scene into a movie clip, so I can play it back with out re-renderering. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: i guess so too, but i don't think its possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this... someone made a really cool library called [FilmStrip](http://labs.animoto.com/2009/06/07/presenting-filmstrip/).

I haven't tried it yet myself, but essentially it outputs each frame to a jpeg and you can turn it into a movie with ffmpeg etc.